# Trying to automatically mail from python script using outlook

Tags: python, automation, outlook, win32com, office-automation

```
ol = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
olmailitem = 0x0
newmail = ol.CreateItem(olmailitem)
newmail.Subject = "Hold Notifier " + row['Ticket ID'] +" | "+ row['N/W Customer Number']+" |"+row['Circuit ID']+" | "+row['Customer Name']+" | "+row['Ticket Priority']+" | "+row['Ticket Region']
newmail.To = 'XXXXXXX@gmail.com'
newmail.CC = 'XXXXX@outlook.com;XXXXXX@gmail.com'
newmail.Body= 'Hello, this is a test email to showcase how to send emails from Python and Outlook.'
newmail.Send()
```

the above code was running fine on my office laptop. But then they allotted me desktop on same id and after registering my code stopped working. what might be issue.

the above code is not giving any error but it does not send mail.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are submitted items sent out when you open Outlook after?

Comment: what other library are you using beside `win32com`?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook may be closed before the item is sent out. If you want to make sure the item is sent out you need to wait until the item is placed to the Sent Items folder in Outlook. The Outlook.exe process may be terminated before that. Set up the `ItemAdd` event handler on the Sent Items folder in Outlook and wait until the item is placed there to be sure the item was sent out.

Another possible reason is a security issue. You may face with a security issue when automating Outlook from an external application. To deal with a safe `Application` object and the entire the Outlook object model you need to develop a COM add-in which can be running along with the host application. In that case you can use standard .net framework techniques for connecting two applications together, for example, .net remoting and etc.

To avoid security issues you can:

1. Use a low-level API which doesn't trigger issues/dialogs in Outlook - Extended MAPI or any third-party wrappers around that API such as Redemption.
2. Use third party components that suppress such issues/dialog in Outlook, for example, see https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php.
3. Develop a COM add-in which can have access to the trusted `Application` object.
4. Install any AV with latest updates.
5. Use GPO to set up settings to not trigger security issues/dialogs.

Read more about that in the ["A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf" warning in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/security/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-email-message-on-your-behalf) article.